# I have two table profile and profil_calculation. the profile table look like

Tags: php, mysql

**profile_table**

```
profile_id profile_name Profile_description
1          VINU         ADMIN
```

**profile_description table**

```
calc_id proile_calc profile_result
1       20            45
2       30            43
3       42            82
```

i want result like.....

```
profile_id profile_name Profile_description calc_id proile_calc profile_result
  1             VINU          ADMIN             1       20            45
                                                2       30            43
                                                3       42            82
```

please help..........

Comment: What's the profile FK in profil_description ? Seems like there is none.

Comment: calc_id in profile_description table is the foreign key of profile_id in profile_table ?

Comment: @AyyappanSekar How can you say that?

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ: I am not saying Bro :) I am asking the questioner, bcoz i cudnt see any of the related fields there

Comment: @AyyappanSekar ohk... misunderstanding.

Comment: Please change the title of your question

Answer (score 0):

it will be like this:

```
SELECT pt.profile_id, pt.profile_name , pt.Profile_description, pd.calc_id , pd.proile_calc, pd.profile_result FROM profile_table as pt LEFT JOIN profile_description as pd ON pt.profile_id = pd.calc_id;
```

or

```
SELECT profile_table.profile_id, profile_table.profile_name , profile_table.Profile_description, profile_description.calc_id , profile_description.proile_calc, profile_description.profile_result FROM profile_table LEFT JOIN profile_description ON profile_table.profile_id = profile_description.calc_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Table is poorly design. No FK in profile_description table. but if i suppose calc_id is FK 
in profile_description table  then 
this query will help you.

SELECT `profile_table`.*,`profile_description`.*
FROM profile_table
RIGHT JOIN profile_description
ON profile_table.profile_id=profile_description.calc_id
```